# Textarea apostrophes becoming backslashes?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a textarea where the user inputs text for a post. I then display the data on the site. How can I prevent the rendering of apostrophes with backslashes in the result? For example:

"Let's do this"

would be:

"Let'\s do this"

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the function [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

However, disabling magic quotes and escaping the input would also be prudent.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Disable magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).
2. [Escape user input in the context of HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, disable magicquotes or strip slashes.

You'll also want to strip tags.  Your website will be vulnerable to attacks if you don't.